# Converting Data frame into a dict with columns as key inside key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame.

```
         mac_address  no. of co_visit    no. of random_visit
0  00:02:1a:11:b0:b9                1                      2
1  00:02:71:d6:04:84                1                      1
2  00:05:33:34:2f:f2                1                      3
3  00:08:22:04:c4:fb                1                      4
4  00:08:22:06:7b:41                1                      1
5  00:08:22:07:48:15                1                      1
6  00:08:22:08:a8:54                1                      3
7  00:08:22:0e:0a:fc                1                      1
```

I want to convert it into a dictionary with mac_address as key and `'no. of co_visit'` and `'no. of random_visit'`  as subkeys inside key and value across that column as value inside subkey. So, my output for first 2 row will be like.

```
00:02:1a:11:b0:b9:{no. of co_visit:1, no. of random_visit: 2}
00:02:71:d6:04:84:{no. of co_visit:1, no. of random_visit: 1}
```

I am using python2.7. Thank you.

I was able to set mac_address as key but the values were being added as list inside key, not key inside key.

Comment: Stackoverflow community is not receptive to questions that ask for help without any evidence of efforts being put into it. Unless you show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck, this question might get closed.

Comment: Well @SuperSaiyan I used to post the whole issue later I have been adviced by moderators to ask where you stuck. so this is a single step which I wasn't able to figure out.

Comment: Mentioning where you are stuck is always great. What you also need to include is your efforts at solving it -- many of us would then be happy to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.T](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [to_dict()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

```
df.set_index('mac_address').T.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'00:02:1a:11:b0:b9': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '2'},
 '00:02:71:d6:04:84': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '1'},
 '00:05:33:34:2f:f2': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '3'},
 '00:08:22:04:c4:fb': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '4'},
 '00:08:22:06:7b:41': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '1'},
 '00:08:22:07:48:15': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '1'},
 '00:08:22:08:a8:54': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '3'},
 '00:08:22:0e:0a:fc': {'no. of co_visit': '1', 'no. of random_visit': '1'}}
```